# Ways of giving 7 identical roses and 5 different cookies

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> In how many ways can we distribute 7 identical roses and 5 different cookies among 4 women, so that no woman gets more than 3 roses?

Comment: For those of you voting to close for lack of context, note that the OP posted an attempted solution in the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cookies are distinguishable, and can thus be distributed in $4^5$ ways. As for the roses, which are not distinguishable, we can distinguish four cases which meet the requirement that no woman should get more than three roses:

1. $(3, 3, 1, 0)$: ${4 \choose 2}{2 \choose 1} = 12$ possibilities
2. $(3, 2, 2, 0)$: ${4 \choose 1}{3 \choose 2} = 12$ possibilities
3. $(3, 2, 1, 1)$: ${4 \choose 1}{3 \choose 1} = 12$ possibilities
4. $(2, 2, 2, 1)$: ${4 \choose 3} = 4$ possibilities

The number of ways to distribute the cookies and the roses thus equals:

$$4^5(12 + 12 + 12 + 4) = 40960$$

Comment: Hey! Tomorrow I am having my discrete mathematics test. Can you please example to be where the numbers came from... Like how did you compute them to come up with the following solutions? I would like an explanation please, and thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Each of the cookies has $4$ possible choices of lady, thus $4^5$ ways

For the roses, we can use [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), and take care of the constraint of $\le3$ by *deliberately* giving $4$ to one of the four women, and subtracting this figure, thus $\binom{10}3 - \binom41\binom63 = 40$

Putting together the pieces, the answer will be $4^5\times 40$

Answer (score 0):

So 4 ladies aren't different so there is just one possibility of giving them roses: {2,2,2,1}.
So the first cookie we can give to 4 different ladies, second also to the 4 different ladies.
so all possiblities are : 5^4
The final is **1* 5^4**
Am I correct?

Comment: This answer should be part of the question that you pose.  Your answer is incorrect.